# Firebase Storage says it can resume downloads. Does S3 have the same feature?

Tags: firebase, amazon-s3, firebase-storage

Firebase Storage says it can resume interrupted downloads. Does S3 also supports this feature or is it Firebase specific?

> Uploads and downloads are robust, meaning they restart where they
>   stopped, saving your users time and bandwidth.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/?hl=en

In addition, this resume feature is handled automatically by their client/server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS API does support `Range` parameter that you can use to download specific part of the file instead of the whole file:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html
If your download was interrupted for some reason feel free to start over where you left.

Some SDKs also include helpers or wrappers to continue downloads. For example, Java SDK has `resumeDownload` method in `TransferManager` class:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#resumeDownload-com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.PersistableDownload-